# PowerShell Uninstall KB 5000802 or 808 Need Elevated Privilege's

Tags: powershell, patch

I have a PowerShell script to uninstall the two problem KB's MS has released, we are pushing it through with our RMM as run PowerShell as admin, but if the user is currently logged in that does not have admin priv. the script errors out with the requested operation requires elevation.  Here is the command being run:

```
Get-WindowsPackage -Online | ?{$_.ReleaseType -like "*Update*"} | 
%{Get-WindowsPackage -Online -PackageName $_.PackageName} | 
?{$_.Description -like "*KB5000802*"} | Remove-WindowsPackage -Online -Restart /quiet
```

Is there some way to get around the elevated privilege's issue?

Comment: While your question is borderline-on-topic, you will likely get many more helpful answers on the StackExchange site [Super User](http://superuser.com/). That is because this is more a "Windows Permissions" question than a "Powershell Script" question. You can simple move the question there if you like, or give it an hour or so here and see if you get a good response.

Comment: How is this different from asking whether a non-admin user can run *anything* that requires elevation?

Comment: Task scheduler seems like a good choice here. Unless you'd like to try removing them remotely passing your creds

Comment: I think the obvious thing to do here is launching the script with a domain admin account that has enough local privileges or use the same process as the one that initially installed the concerned KB updates.